# VCO tuning voltage range starting from higher than 0 V

Tags: voltage, pll, vco, tuning

I have seen some VCO datasheets. In every datasheet, I see that the tuning voltage range starts from some value above 0 V (like 0.5 V, 1 V etc). So, what would be the frequency at 0 V? And why do they write the range from above 0 V and not 0 V?

I will be using a ~580 MHz VCO controlled by a PLL, so I need to understand what will happen when the system starts and how will the initialization process be. The PLL would not likely start with the loop filter pumped up to 0.5 or 1 V, it should start at 0 V with no charge in the filter capacitors.

So, what would be going on in the beginning?

Comment: *So, what would be the voltage at 0 V?* It would be 0 V. You mean: what would the **frequency** be at 0 V? Look at the datasheet. If that is not mentioned then it is anyone's guess and you also cannot rely on operation when Vtune = 0 V. Most VCOs are not mean to be used that way.

Comment: Often these VCOs rely on a varicap / varactor (diode used in reverse mode so that it is also a variable capacitor) and to get a reliable capacitance, some reverse DC voltage needs to be applied across the varactor. The predictable behavior starts are around 0.5 V DC.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage tuned oscillators in the 580 MHz range use varactor diodes as the tuning elements.

Chances are that your VCO will still run at 0 V tuning voltage (it might not), and will have a frequency lower than its lowest advertised frequency (so should not cause a problem with loop acquisition).

There are several things that 'go wrong' with a varactor in a VCO in the very low voltage range, around 0 V to 1 V or even a little higher.

- Capacitance and hence frequency is difficult to specify as accurately as at higher voltages, as the capacitance/voltage slope gets very steep there. It just makes putting reliable numbers on the VCO data sheet harder.
- The RF swing of the VCO may take the varactor into conduction if there's not enough tuning voltage on it. This will make the oscillator suddenly very noisy (phase noise).
- Even without forward conduction, operation at low voltage / high capacitance means the diode generally delivers lower Q, so the VCO is a bit noisier at low tuning voltages.
- If the VCO has not been designed to cope with the large change in capacitance at low voltages, then it could stop oscillating. A VCO might be designed carefully around good noise at some higher tune voltage, and the possibility of it stopping at low voltages may be acceptable.